# How to repeat a word document template for multiple records in BIRT RPT

Tags: ms-word, apache-poi, birt, doc, rpt

I have a word template.need to fill data based on a webservice response.If response has multiple records then i need to generate multiple pages of same template in single document instead of generating multiple files.
how can i achieve it using BIRT RPT.
because if i use Apache POI the formating of text is missing.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with BIRT, because BIRT is not meant to be a template processor.